# TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly using Python3.5

Tags: python

I am using Python 3.5 on the following code.

```
def raxml(DIR,cleaned,num_cores,seqtype):
        assert cleaned.endswith(".aln-cln"),\
                "raxml infile "+cleaned+" not ends with .aln-cln"
        assert seqtype == "aa" or seqtype == "dna","Input data type: dna or aa"
        assert len(read_fasta_file(DIR+cleaned)) >= 4,\
                "less than 4 sequences in "+DIR+cleaned
        clusterID = cleaned.split(".")[0]
        tree = DIR+clusterID+".raxml.tre"
        raw_tree = "RAxML_bestTree."+cleaned
        model = "PROTCATWAG" if seqtype == "aa" else "GTRCAT"
        if not os.path.exists(tree) and not os.path.exists(raw_tree):
                # raxml crashes if input file starts with . 
                infasta = cleaned if DIR == "./" else DIR+cleaned
                cmd = ["raxml","-T",str(num_cores),"-p","12345","-s",\
                       infasta,"-n",cleaned,"-m",model]
                print (" ".join(cmd))
                p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
                out = p.communicate()
                assert p.returncode == 0,"Error raxml"+out[0]
        try:
                os.rename(raw_tree,tree)
                os.remove("RAxML_info."+cleaned)
                os.remove("RAxML_log."+cleaned)
                os.remove("RAxML_parsimonyTree."+cleaned)
                os.remove("RAxML_result."+cleaned)
                os.remove(DIR+cleaned+".reduced")
        except: pass # no need to worry about extra intermediate files
        return tree
```

It runs and returns the following code:

```
"raxml_wrapper.py", line 30, in raxml
        assert p.returncode == 0,"Error raxml"+out[0]
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Initially, I tried the following:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 p = p.decode('utf-8')
 out = p.communicate()
 assert p.returncode == 0,"Error raxml"+out[0]
```

That didn't fix the issue at all. I have looked at similar questions, but I cannot come up with a solution to this. I would appreciate some help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume Python3?

Comment: try `binascii` ... `import binascii` and then `print(binascii.hexlify(bytes_here).decode())`

Comment: @Mick_ does binascii covert bytes to string

Comment: binascii can represent your bytes as string of hex values with your data. It's hard to advise on better solution unless you provide some information on how you intend to use the data.

Answer (score 1):

`p`, a `Popen` object, doesn't have a `.decode(...)` member.

You need to actually decode the *output*

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, _ = p.communicate()
out = out.decode('utf-8')
assert p.returncode == 0, 'Error raxml' + out[0]
```

That said, this code can be improved to use `subprocess.check_output`:

```
# does roughly the same thing, you'll get `subprocess.CalledProcessError` instead of `AssertionError`
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode('UTF-8')
```

Or if you happen to be using python3.6+

```
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: Hello @Anthony I'm still getting an assert error message this time: AssertionError: Error raxml

Comment: This is what I have added thus far, to find a solution: out, _ = p.communicate()
  out = subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode('UTF-8')
  print (out)
  assert p.returncode == 0,"Error raxml"+ out[0]

Comment: ah, you need to use my solutions *separately*, the three code blocks are options that do roughly the same thing (don't use both of them!)

Comment: My mistake @Anthony I just used the first block as it is. I am still getting the assertion error: Error raxml.

Comment: probably means your command is exiting nonzero -- what happens when you run it in a terminal separately? (maybe inspect `echo $?` after running?)

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming and using python. How may I go about doing this?

Comment: let's say `cmd` is `['echo', 'hi']` open up a terminal and type `echo hi; echo $?` -- it should print `hi` and then `0` (it exited successfully).  In your case, you need to run `raxml -T ...; echo $?` and see what it returns -- it's possible (probable?) that your invocation is off.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction, so I used echo as you specified and it says :  , exiting ...
255

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what your p.communicate() method does, but it seems that it returns a byte object as a result. And this piece of code, cannot add this byte object to "Error raxml" str object:

```
assert p.returncode == 0,"Error raxml"+out[0]
```

Maybe you should try converting it to str as this:

```
assert p.returncode == 0,"Error raxml"+str(out[0])
```